# Add Confidence Score to Azure Cognitive Services Web App

Tags: azure, computer-vision, azure-cognitive-services

I created an Azure Web App with Microsoft Computer Vision to Tag images I upload and write a Description. I followed this tutorial: https://github.com/Microsoft/computerscience/blob/master/Labs/Azure%20Services/Azure%20Storage/Azure%20Storage%20and%20Cognitive%20Services%20(MVC).md#Exercise1

The app tags the images, but I can not see the Confidence Score for the tags. Anyone had this problem before or do you have any tips on how to add the confidence scores? Help is appreciated

Best regards,
Daniel

Comment: Please provide at least an [mcve]. A short answer: as far as I can see in the example, the confidence score is bever stored in, for instance, metadata.

Answer (score 0):

The sample application uses the [/describe](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5adf991815e1060e6355ad44/operations/56f91f2e778daf14a499e1fe) endpoint, which does not return the confidence score for tags as they are intended merely to add contextual hints to the computer-generated description.

To get the tag confidences, you need to use the [/analyze?visualFeatures=tags](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5adf991815e1060e6355ad44/operations/56f91f2e778daf14a499e1fa) endpoint.